# Why does tsc ignore include and exclude in tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig

I have `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "ES6"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/server/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "public"
  ]
}
```

and when I ran `tsc --project tsconfig.json` it totally ignored the `include` and `exclude` configuration and failed on `node_modules` compilation.

The only way it succeeded was `tsc src/server/**/*.ts`, but then it did not use the config.

I verified, that the compiler processes the config, because when I added `"watch": true` to `"compilerOptions"`, it waited for change.

I looked at [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) and I didn't get it. It looked like I placed it on correct position in the json file.

Does anyone have any idea, how to fix it?

---

Compiler version on macOS Big Sur:

```
% tsc -v
Version 4.0.5
```

Comment: Try to add "skipLibCheck":true to your tsconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in comment below the issue, I had to add `"skipLibCheck": true`, so the final json looks like:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "ES6"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/server/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "public"
  ]
}
```

Then compilation succeeds:

```
% tsc -p tsconfig.json 
% echo $?
0
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I solved it but upgrading typescript:

```
npm install -g typescript
```